# How can I make ValidationSummary appear on my MVC4 web page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

When I code my Razor HTML like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl })) {
   @Html.ValidationSummary()
}
```

I get the following which is just what I want:

```
<div class="validation-summary-valid" data-valmsg-summary="true">
<ul>
<li style="display:none"></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

However what I need for the form is the following:

```
<form class="form" data-href="/User/Account/Register" id="registerForm">
   @Html.ValidationSummary()
</form>
```

With the above code I don't get the validation-summary-valid class. Can
someone explain why this is or maybe suggest how I could code 
HTML.BeginForm so that I can get the form definition that I need.

Comment: Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/a/6813634/639343 can help you

Comment: @archil - I looked at this but it still doesn't really explain why I don't see any validation div if I just specify form and don't use Html.BeginForm.

Comment: Maybe you should initialize FormContext. That is what Html.BeginForm does

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the overloaded BeginForm to include HtmlAttributes:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("action", "controller", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form", @id = "registerForm", data_href = "/User/Account/Register" }))
{
    ....
}
```

The view engine won't parse "data-href" so you have to use an underscore instead of a hyphen.

Answer (score 0):

At the top of your view try the following

ViewContext.FormContext = new FormContext();