# list depends on the change in the index of dropdownlist in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, html-select

I have two things in my view 'ListUrl.cshtml'
a dropdown list filled with the names of URLs.
a list where I 'URLs' as the first column capitals.

What I want is that when I select an item from the dropdown list, the list is automatically adjusted according to the selection. when I select a URL then I only see that url in the list.

In Model:

```
public class UrlItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string urlll { get; set; }
    public int toontijd { get; set; }
    public int positie { get; set; }
}
```

In HomeController:

```
public ViewResult ListUrl()
    {
        var ws = new Service1();

        localhost.Service1 s1 = new Service1();
        localhost.UrlInfo[] ui = s1.GetOrders();

        Models.ListUrl.UrlList = new List<OrderItem>();

        for (int i = 0; i < ui.Length; i++)
        {
            var OrderItem = new OrderItem();
            OrderItem.Id = Convert.ToInt32(ui[i].Id);
            OrderItem.urlll = ui[i].url;
            OrderItem.toontijd = ui[i].ToonTijd;
            OrderItem.positie  = Convert.ToInt32(ui[i].positie);

            Models.ListUrl.UrlList.Add(OrderItem);
        }

        //return result;
        var urlname = from url in s1.GetUrlInfo() select url  ;
        ViewData["url"] = new SelectList(urlname, "Id", "url");



        return View();

    }
```

And in the View:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DropDownList("url", (SelectList)ViewData["url"], "---All")
    </th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>
        Url
    </th>
    <th>
        ...
    </th>
    <th>             
    </th>
    <th>
        ...
    </th>
</tr>

@foreach (var item in ListUrl.UrlList)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @item.urlll.ToString()        
        </td>
        <td>
            @item.toontijd.ToString()

        </td>
        <td>

        </td>
        <td>
            @item.positie.ToString()
        </td>
    </tr>

}
```

I hope someone can help this mvc beginner :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to either pull down the entire list (in your secondary drop down) first, then use Javascript to remove any unwanted entries after the first drop down selection.  Or you can make an Ajax call to retrieve the list of secondary values after the first is selected.  Either way, some client side stuff has to happen.  See my post below, the example code does exactly what you are trying to do using ajax calls that return partial views.

[MVC3 Unobtrusive Validation Not Working after Ajax Call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7048726/mvc3-unobtrusive-validation-not-working-after-ajax-call)

Comment: Sorry, when you said "when I select an item from the dropdown list, the list is automatically adjusted according to the selection", I assumed you meant a secondary drop down.  Regardless of whether its a drop down, or a regular "html" list, if it's being dynamically built, the approach is EXACTLY the same.

Comment: Hi David, I have a dropdown list and a list (table with rows which are dynamically filled with data), if you look at my code, you can see that it is not a question of two DropDownLists.

Comment: can u tell me please, because mvc for me it's Chinese.
if I want to use the script to the list instead of dropdownlist what should I do?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You still need to make an AJAX call or do client side filtering.  Its just that you return an HTML list of items instead of an html select.  The code is exactly the same as far as the AJAX request.  Try figuring out what the ajax functions in the scripting on the link I sent you, and you will understand what you need to do.

Comment: Thank you David, I did not understand or we do not understand each other anyway thanks for the effort.