# Validation on async loaded Partial View Forms not firing.

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I am loading partial views  by calling the server preredendering the content on the server and dumping the returned html to the page.  This is then displayed in a div on the page.  The partial view contains all the functionality for this form including the javascript to make the ajax calls.
I can make everything work in this but the form validation that would come over automaticly if  the partial view was written during the initial page load.

I am thinking that something has to get tied together.  Perhaps some portion of the validation is only tied in on a full page load and not on the partial render.  I just need to figure out the javascript call that needs to happen to have it work correctly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MVC3 Unobtrusive Validation Not Working after Ajax Call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7048726/mvc3-unobtrusive-validation-not-working-after-ajax-call).

Answer (score 0):

did you use following line in your partial view

```
Html.EnableClientValidation(true);
Html.EnableUnobtrusiveJavaScript(true);
```

Please add reference of following js:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I hope this will help!