# jquery Validation works half way

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-validate

Hi I am struggeling with the jquery validation.

I have a requirement to draw a form dynamically. Depending on the parameters that the users set up. I have to validate these input fields then when the user submits this form. I got it working by adding the class='required' to all the inputs that i want to validate.

This works 80%, it validates the first 6 fields on the page, but not the rest. On the fields that is not validated on form submit, i just need to click in the input with my mouse and then leave the input again, then the validation is fired.

Am i missing something with the validation.

Here is how i determine when/when not the field should be validated.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => param.SelectedDate, new {@class = (!param.IsNullable) ? "required" : "", @id = param.Parameter.Name, coltype = "date" })
```

Like I Said it works, just not on the form submit, and not for all the fields.

please help

Answer (score 1):

This may be the same issue I had awhile back: [Trouble getting unobtrusive validation working with mvc 3 on jquery ajax post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7005052/trouble-getting-unobtrusive-validation-working-with-mvc-3-on-jquery-ajax-post/7019587#7019587)

You may have to rebuild the validators since you added controls dynamically:

```
$.validator.unobtrusive.parse($('form'))
```

Comment: thanks for the response, tried your code, but still no success. because the validation works on focus(),blur(), i created a function, that before form submit it focus and blur all the textboxes, probably not the best solution, but workable for now.

here is the function if someone needs it

     function bnClick() {
        $(":text").each(function () {
            $(this).focus();
            $(this).blur();
        });
    }